# Can't understand how I get a certain value from an array when a function is called using recursive method

Tags: javascript, recursion

Ok, first, sorry for the not so clear question.

Here's the thing:

```
function sum(arr, n) {
// Only change code below this line
if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
}
// Only change code above this line
}

var a = sum([2, 3, 4], 1);
console.log(a);
```

When `a` is called the result will be 2. I want to know which value will replace `arr` in the `sum(arr, n - 1)`. Isn't supposed to be like `arr[]` so that I can pull the on of the three numbers from the array instead?

Comment: ‘arr’ is ‘[2,3,4]’ and it always will be

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Were you expecting a different result than `2`?  If so, what result and why?

Comment: What is your expected output?
The sun(arr, n-1) will use the same array reference, the function was called with.

Comment: What will be the result of `sum(arr, n - 1)`? How the mat is done here to get to that result? like what is the next step after i get `sum(arr, 0)`?

Comment: @Ualmeida: Well, since in the initial call to `sum` the value of `n` was `1`, then a call to `sum(arr, n - 1)` would be the same as `sum([2, 3, 4], 0)`.  You can test that to see what the result is.  Thogh the very first `if` block in `sum` is pretty straightforward...

Comment: @David Ok, so how `sum([2, 3, 4], 0)` will be equal to `2` in order to be `2 + 0` which will be the final result of `2`?

Comment: @Ualmeida: It's not.  It's equal to `0`.  The final result is `2` because `arr[n - 1]` is equal to `2`.

Comment: @David so it's `0` because it's [2x3x4]x0, correct?

Comment: @Ualmeida: It's not clear what you're referring to there.  Why are you multiplying?  Where in the code is any multiplying taking place?  This is probably a good opportunity for you to start using a debugger.  (There's one built in to most browsers that you can use for JavaScript on a web page.)  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe the exact behavior.  When you do this, which specific operation produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @David Ok, will do that. TY

Answer (score 0):

For ex.

> sum([2, 3, 4], 1) = sum([2, 3, 4], 0) + 2
>
> sum([2, 3, 4], 0) = 0

So result will be;

> sum([2, 3, 4], 1) = 0 + 2
>
> sum([2, 3, 4], 1) = 2